# How to print out butcher's algorithm python

Tags: python

I have to do an assignment in which I have ask for a year and the program should print out the upcoming date of easter. I realised that I have to use butcher's algorithm, but I can't figure out how to print it because I don't understand why self is there? Could you please tell me what I should do in order to print out the date?

```
from datetime import date

def calc_easter(self, year):
    a = year % 19
    b = year // 100
    c = year % 100
    d = (19 * a + b - b // 4 - ((b - (b + 8) // 25 + 1) // 3) + 15) % 30
    e = (32 + 2 * (b % 4) + 2 * (c // 4) - d - (c % 4)) % 7
    f = d + e - 7 * ((a + 11 * d + 22 * e) // 451) + 114
    month = f // 31
    day = f % 31 + 1    
    return date(year, month, day)
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. _but I can't figure out how to print it because I don't understand why self is there?_ What does that have to do with it? Printing and the role of the self parameter in methods are not exactly related topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So unless this code is a part of a class, `self` should not be there.

And for printing, did you try to use `print(calc_easter(2020))`?

Comment: You are welcome!
Just make sure to close the question!

Answer (score 2):

`self` is used to represent the instance of a class here. In your case, you won't need it because if this is all your code is, you would need to delete the `self` parameter otherwise you would get the following when you try to just enter a year as the parameter:

```
TypeError: calc_easter() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Your code would then be:

```
from datetime import date

def calc_easter(year):
    a = year % 19
    b = year // 100
    c = year % 100
    d = (19 * a + b - b // 4 - ((b - (b + 8) // 25 + 1) // 3) + 15) % 30
    e = (32 + 2 * (b % 4) + 2 * (c // 4) - d - (c % 4)) % 7
    f = d + e - 7 * ((a + 11 * d + 22 * e) // 451) + 114
    month = f // 31
    day = f % 31 + 1    
    return date(year, month, day)
```

To convert it to an (easier to read) date and see it, you could do this:

```
"{:%B %d, %Y}".format(calc_easter(year=2002))

Output: 'March 31, 2002'
```